# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() with simple quotes

Tags: java, runtime, runtime.exec

I have a problem with Java `Runtime` in Linux. I need to execute this command:

> blastdbcmd -db '"mydb"' -info

So I use this Java code :

```
 String[] cmd = new String[] {blastdbcmd ,"-db", "\'","\"", mydb,"\"","\'","-info"}  
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
 p.waitFor();
```

but it doesn't work: every time I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception...
can anybody help me?

If I try with :

> blastdbcmd -db "mydb" -info

it works, but the simple quotes are necessary if I have a command like

> blastdbcmd -db "mydb mydb2" -info

Comment: `blastdbcmd` isn't enclosed in a string i.e. "blastdbcmd". If that isn't the problem then where do you get the NullPointerExcepiton?

Comment: @EmilH If `blastdbcmd` isn't a variable that contains a String he'll get a compile error, not a NullPointerException (which is a runtime error).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist No. `String blastdbcmd = null` would cause no compilation error and would cause a NPE.

Comment: @EmilH True. I was thinking only of the case where it's undeclared, not uninitialised.

Answer (score 1):

If the blastdbcmd is expecting arguments with literal double quote characters them:

```
String[] cmd = new String[] {"blastdbcmd", "-db", "\"mydb mydb2\"", "-info"};
```

which is equivalent to

```
$ blastdbcmd -db "\"mydb mydb2\"" -info
```

If not:

```
String[] cmd = new String[] {"blastdbcmd", "-db", "mydb mydb2", "-info"};
```

which is equivalent to

```
$ blastdbcmd -db "mydb mydb2" -info
```